# powershell execute .exe remotely

Tags: powershell

```
$computername = Read-Host "Enter Machine Name - "

Invoke-command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c 'c:\download\niniteone\niniteone.exe' /select "malwarebytes"}
```

Wondering if someone could tell me where I've gone wrong with this, it just dies when I run it. I've put this script together by looking at the others here but I can't seem to get it to work. We use ninite pro to update/install some 3rd party apps and I'm trying to setup some powershell scripts to run it on remote computers. Any help would be appreciated :)

***Update*** - I added the cmd /c to the script block and now it works great!? I read cmd /c isnt needed with powershell v2? I'm confused... It's working but I'd like to get it right.

Comment: It shouldn't "just die." What error messages are you getting? Anything in the remote computer's event log? Is `niniteone.exe` designed to run in a non-interactive mode?

Comment: I dont get an error message - when I run it I just get the powershell prompt and then I check the computer and it's not doing anything. It's like nothing happened..

Comment: I dont think it likes my arguments but not sure how to set that up.

Comment: The exe exists at that location on the "remote" machine, right?

Comment: Yes the .exe exists I can run it from the command line using enter-pssession and the cmd /c c:\...

Comment: I used this guys script and it runs great but it requires me to input the whole command line each time which I'd like to avoid. - http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/56962f03-0243-4c83-8cdd-88c37898ccc4

Comment: Execute `$error.clear()`, then run invoke-command.  Afterwards execute `$error[0] | fl * -force` to see if any error info is getting logged.  BTW are these  domain joined PCs?  Are you running the command from an elevated prompt with credentials that also have Admin privileges on the remote machine?  You might try a command known to work e.g. `icm -cn $computerName { $psversiontable }` and see if you get any output (or error).

Comment: Well I added cmd /c to it and now it's working, I thought cmd /c was old and isnt needed anymore?                                           $computername = Read-Host "Enter Machine Name - "                      
Invoke-command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c 'c:\download\niniteone\niniteone.exe' /select "malwarebytes"}

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "c:\download\niniteone\niniteone.exe" -ArgumentList "/select `"malwarebytes`""}
```